# C++ : vector.erase(this)

Tags: c++, vector

I have an `std::vector` that holds all the objects and is passed to them in every frame, so that every object can access other objects. My question is how can an object can delete itself from the vector?

This doesn't work:

```
vector.erase(this);
```

Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: An important detail is missing. Unfortunately I don't have any idea what it might be.

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed more code or a minimal test case that shows how you are doing it and what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delete the element by accessing its iterator, this can be done through `std::find`, or if you know the index (less complexity) through:

```
vector.begin() + indexOfElement
```

so that you can delete it:

```
vector<Type>::iterator it = yourVector.begin() + index;
yourVector.erase(it);
```

Mind that, since a vector stores its data in an array format, **this causes all elements after the one you are deleting to be shifted to the left (which is expensive)**. Consider using a `std::list` instead if you don't need random access.

Answer (score 8):

`erase` requires an iterator. `this` is a pointer available within member functions/class definition. Also, `erase` needs to be called on an instance of `vector` -- you cannot use `vector.erase`.

The object can't delete itself. You will need to pass an iterator. You can use `std::find` to find if the object exists within the vector and then pass that along.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use a set and use set.erase(this)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can use std::find ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/ ) This requires you to overload the == operator if I'm not mistaken.

For example

```
std::vector<YourObjectType>::iterator it = find(yourVector.begin(), yourVector.end(), referenceToObject);

bool operator == (const YourObjectType* object) {return object == this; }
```

And then you just use `yourVector.erase(it);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
vec.erase(vec.begin() + (this - &vec.front()));
```

if you are sure that the element is from the vector indeed